# DQN on recommendation system

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recommendation-engine, q-learning

I want to use DQN on recommendation system for retail industry

but the problem is, the state space of this question are time-inhomogeneous & not deterministic

(compare to Atari games)

I figure out two method for this problem

- make state-transition become deterministic
- use historical data to calculate transition probabilities, use probabilities to transit state

but...both of them seems not make sense

somebody [point out](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3eeg6v/leveraging_google_%20deepmind_software_and_deep/) this kind issues

if I want to build a recommendation system based on Reinforcement Learning

where should I start?